# how to duplicate lines according to number of values in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

To formulate better my question, i am trying to create a formula in google sheets where i have one table with users and role, user 1 - Accountant, user 2 - finances, user 3 - seller and a second table with number of trips, trip 1, trip 2, trip 3, what i need the formula to do is to for each trip get the users that are not seller and create one line for each of them, for example:

| Trip | User | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| trip 1 | User 1 | Accountant |
| trip 1 | User 2 | Finances |
| trip 2 | User 1 | Accountant |
| trip 2 | User 2 | Finances |
| trip 3 | User 1 | Accountant |
| trip 3 | User 2 | Finances |

I was trying to query the data but with no success, can someone help me out?
I have the link for an example table for more solid understanding

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit?usp=sharing)

tried to create a query function with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A7:A9&"#"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A4&"#"&B2:B4,B2:B4<>"Seller"))),"#"))
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer! Is there a way to enhanced so every time a new line of travel 4, travel 5 increases the lines of users keep being added too? because if i increase the range and add a new travel line its not following the rule, or even if i encrease the range and the cell is empty still adds users